# Correct way to ask "What's the topic for the inside board this month/ for this month"?

Tags: word-usage

We have two boards (one inside the class and another outside the class) where charts are put up every month.  We get a topic each month. So what is a natural way to ask the "inside board topic?

> What's the topic for the inside board this month?
>
> What's the inside board topic this month?
>
> What's the inside board topic for this month?
>
> What's the topic for the inside board for this month?

What out of the four sounds the most natural to you?

Answer (score 1):

Only the last one seems particularly unnatural, at least, in casual speech.

*"What's the topic for the inside board for this month?"* has that duplication of **for** which is a little awkward to me.

Assuming "the inside board" is a object that is well-understood by your class and the fact that its content changes every month is also well-understood, any of the first three would be OK, but you may need to pause slightly between certain words when you are saying them – a comma might indicate this in writing:

- *"What's the topic for the inside board, this month?"*
- *"What's the inside board topic, this month?"*
- *"What's the inside board topic, for this month?"*

Be careful with the placement of the comma/pause, though—particularly with the third sentence—if you misplace it, another reader may take a different meaning:

- *"What's the inside board topic for, this month?"* could be interepreted as *"Why is there an inside board, this month?"*

To that end, I would favour the first sentence (with my comma before *this month*) in a written question; and the second sentence (where my comma is a slight pause) in a verbal question.